# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V

Tags: java, hibernate, persistência

Trabalho em um projeto Java e ao mudar de máquina precisei informar novamente as bibliotecas do projeto, porém ao compilar esta gerando um erro na saída.

Saída:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.build(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:245)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1020)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:835)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52)
```

Porém não sei onde procurar pelo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eu já tive problemas semelhantes a este por usar versões diferentes de alguma biblioteca.

Confirma se as bibliotecas da máquina nova são as mesmas da antiga.

Comment: realmente alguns jar estavam na versão mais antiga.